# Change rendering mode of chrome

Tags: browser

Aosp browser rendered text and pictures a lot differently then chrome.

It would white box what is rendered while the cpu and stuff catches up.  Chrome seems to freeze when CPU strapped.  Is there a way to fix this or revert to the old behavior at minimum?

Alternatively is there a way to install the original browser in android 6?

Not to mention this http://cdn.androidbeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/sunspider_benchmark1.png

Comment: Chrome has seemed to get better with time.

Answer (score -1):

I can't guarantee that you'll get a quick fix by trying this out. But I can tell you that it will change your browser for the better. You'll just have to try one option after another and or together because there's about 30 or 40 options you can enable but here you try . ( Chrome://Flags ) type that into your Chrome browser and start ticking off the flags that look like they may help .

Comment: There is no option for this under Chrome.